# assigning value to array index returns SIGSEGV; segmentation fault. | c

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault on line 28 of the code below. ***note: the program is not finished.***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    // get data
    FILE* raw = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    int rawLength = 0;
    while(fgetc(raw) != EOF){
        rawLength++;
    }

    char dat[rawLength + 1];
    fread(dat, 1, rawLength + 1, raw);

    // separate data into blocks
    int data[sizeof(dat) / 512][512];

    data[0][0] = atoi(*dat[0]); // <----------- this is line 28 where the error is happening.

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(data) / 4; i += 512)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 512; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = atoi(*dat[i + j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to open a raw file called "card.raw", and read its contents and size. Then it checks for jpegs inside the file using the official jpeg header: "0xff 0xd8 0xff [something from 0xe0 to 0xef]".

For now this is all it does but when I'm finished with it, it should save every jpeg it finds in a new file. Basically, it's a jpeg recovery system since your devices' trash bin folder is similar to that. All I'm asking is you figure out the error; you don't need to write an entire recovery program if you can't right now. **thanks for the help! :)**

Comment: Why don't you try to debug it? If you can't use a debugger, add prints. For example, check/print the value of `rawLength`, the length of `dat` after you read into it from `raw` file. My guess is that `dat` is not `'\0'` terminated but you can figure it out without help from Stackoverflow.

Comment: It is not clear if the contents of the file will be something actually fine for `atoi`; anyway it should not crash unless dat is not null terminated. Add a `memset (dat, 0, sizeof (dat));` just after its declaration `char dat[rawLength + 1];`. In the worst case the array will contain a 0 in its last position.

Comment: `fread` doesn't read anything. After `fgetc`return `EOF`, it's the End Of File - there's nothing more to `fread`. What is the value of `rawLength`? Also, I do not believe you understand what `atoi` does. What do you expect on the output? Does the file store a zero terminated string?

Comment: thank you @KamilCuk for the tip but i'm still getting the same problem at the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my understanding atoi converts char* string to an integer.
So i think chars outside of '0-9' won't work. i'll check for hex and binary later.

Comment: what do you mean by "chars outside of '0-9'"?

Comment: really sorry about the confusion. i wanted to do "atoi(*...)" not "atoi(&...)". i just fixed it in an edit.

Comment: what i'm trying to say is 1 and '1' are different, so using atoi() to convert it would expect a string made of chars "0-9" not int 0 - 9, if the 1st chars of your file was "0xff" then it returns the number, but 0xff is ascii[0xff].

Comment: ok. thanks for the explanation. i changed `data[i][j] = atoi(*dat[i + j]);` to `data[i][j] = atoi(*((string)dat[i + j]));` but it still wont work [:<].

Comment: To read data from a file use normal fread(..), If you're sure it's a string of numbers use atoi. then signature of jpeg i saw was hex not a string of hex.